# Count co-occurences from a dataframe with ids

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyr, expand

I realize there are a lot of similar questions but they all tackle a slightly different problem and I have been stuck for a while.

I have a `dataframe` of all unique combinations of 2 variables as follows:

```
df = data.frame(id = c('c1','c2','c3','c2','c3','c1','c3'),
                groupid = c('g1','g1','g1','g2','g2','g3','g3'))
```

And I need the following output:

```
   c1 c2 c3
c1  3  1  2
c2  1  3  2
c3  2  2  3
```

In other words I need to count how often each pair of customer ids occur in the same group.

Seems like a basic question, but I can't figure it out. I tried:

1. making a cross join to find all possible combinations of `(cid1,groupid,cid2)`
2. looping through all of them and retrieving unique groups that match `cid1` and unique groups that match `cid2`
3. taking the length of the intersection

..but this would take forever to run, so I am looking for an efficient and preferably clean solution (using `tidyr`/`dplyr`).

Answer (score 2):

We may use `crossprod` after getting the frequency count with `table` on the two columns

```
crossprod(table(df[2:1]))
```

Comment: perhaps a shorter one `tcrossprod(table(df))` :P